# How to escape ampersand before serializing JSON string

Tags: c#, json, serialization

I have my cart object that I am serializing to throw it into a cookie.  That all works fine.  But when I go to deserialize it on the other side I get this error:

> Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReaderException: Unterminated string. Expected delimiter: ". Path 'ShoppingCart[0].productName', line 1, position 221.

I have determined that the error is getting thrown on the ampersand character.

My serialize code looks like this:

```
 string myObjectJson =JsonConvert.SerializeObject( cart );
```

And my deserialize code:

```
csm = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<CartSummaryModel>( myCookie.Values[ "Cart" ] );
```

I have tried putting `HttpUtility.HtmlEncode` in front of `JsonConvert` but that doesn't do what I want it to do.

Here is my full string after running the serialize on it:

> {"ShoppingCart":[{"productIDs":[],"productNames":[],"productPrices":[],"productDescriptions":[],"imref":"24251","intDBQty":172,"isFrozen":false,"ProdId":"2063","productName":"Family Inspriration Gift Bags includes Tissue & Gift Tags, Set of 5","productPrice":14.0,"ProductDesc":"\"A Special Gift, for a Special Someone!\"  These inspirational gift bags are ideal for wrapping small to medium-sized gifts.  Includes white tissue, gift tags, and secure cord handles.  8\"L x 4 3/4\"W x 10 1/2\"H.  Set of 5","productQuantity":1}],"TotalQty":1,"SubTotalCost":14.0,"TotalCost":22.0,"TotalDiscount":0.0,"ReferralCode":"","ReferralEmail":"","TotalShipping":8.0,"FreeShipMin":70.0,"TotalProcessing":0.0,"ShipText":"Est. Ship","TotalTax":0.0,"TaxText":"Est. Tax","OERef":"","CartNum":"","Message":"","LowQuantity":false,"HasFrozen":false}

Comment: "unterminated string"? That has nothing to do with `&`... `&` is not a JS metachar, and doesn't need to be escaped. `"&"` is a complete/valid JSON string.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After converting your object to JSON string use
 `HttpUtility.UrlEncode(myObjectJson)` and when deserializing use `HttpUtility.UrlDecode(myCookie.Values["Cart"])`